# Autocommand not working in Vim, how to set makeprg based upon the filetype?

Tags: vim

I use Vim editor for programming and here's the problem that I am facing.

I am using multiple tabs to edit C++ and Python files simultaneously and I have added the following in my .vimrc file

```
filetype plugin indent on
au filetype python set mp=python3\ %
au filetype cpp set mp=g++\ -Werror\ -Wextra\ -Wall\ -ansi\ -pedantic-errors\ -g\ %
```

i.e all I want is that when I switch to a tab with a Python file and run `:make`, it should run `:!python3 %`, and when I switch to a tab with a C++ file and run `:make` it should run `:!g++ -Werror -Wextra -Wall -ansi -pedantic-errors -g %`

However it's not working, and everytime I switch the tab and run `:make`, it tries to execute `!g++ -Werror -Wextra -Wall -ansi -pedantic-errors -g %` and when I run `:set ft?` on the 2 files(i.e Python and C++) to check whether the filetypes have been correctly identified or not, I get the correct result i.e python and cpp.

Then why is this autocommand not working? Am I missing something?
Thanks for your patience

Comment: AFAIK makecmd is not tied to a buffer, so the last executed command wins.

Comment: Solved

au BufRead,BufEnter,BufNewFile *.cpp,*.C set mp=g++\ -Werror\ -Wextra\ -Wall\ -ansi\ -pedantic-errors\ -g\ %
au BufRead,BufEnter,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw set mp=python3\ %

Answer (score 9):

Try using `setlocal` instead of `set`. e.g.:

```
filetype plugin indent on
au filetype python setlocal mp=python3\ %
au filetype cpp setlocal mp=g++\ -Werror\ -Wextra\ -Wall\ -ansi\ -pedantic-errors\ -g\ %
```

If you read [`:help mp`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'makeprg'), you'll see that the setting is 'global or local to buffer  [global-local](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#global-local)'. This means that you can use `set` to apply a makeprg globally, or `setlocal` to override it for a single buffer.